# ui-router to resolve same object but with different data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following example which resolves an existing product `code` by returning the results from my DB `(ProductsFactory.getProduct)` and then enters my `editProduct` state:

```
.state('editProduct', {
    url: '/products/:code', 
    resolve: {
        product: ['$stateParams', 'ProductsFactory',
            function($stateParams, ProductsFactory) {
                return ProductsFactory.getProduct( $stateParams.code );
        }]
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/products/product.edit.html',
    controller: 'EditProductController', 
    authenticate: true, 
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.user, USER_ROLES.admin]
    } 
})
```

What I am wanting to know... is it possible to pass in a new product `code` that doesn't resolve from the database but still enters my `editProduct` state?

I want to either send an existing product `code` which returns all information about the product, or send a new product `code` which still returns a product but only contains the product code in the array.

Comment: have you ever worked on local storage?

Comment: @Sravan not much, but I don't actually follow?

Comment: @Riples Check out the my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
 return ProductsFactory.getProduct( $stateParams.code );
```

Don't use this in the resolve. If it is a db call, it may take time to enter into the page.

Add this call in the controller initialize where you can get the necessary data for that page.

I guess, if it fails you may get the blank page.

Comment: So are you saying I should enter into my state without a resolve, and then query my DB inside the controller?

Comment: Yes. You can use resolve to load the angular controller, services files and css files

Comment: this seemed to be the most practical solution for me.  I removed the resolve as directed and added code to the controller to load in my data based on the $stateParams.  The only issue I have is that I have a loader animation attached to the resolve, which now won't exist if the user needs to wait for the page to load.

Comment: Please check the following article https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1039826/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs-and-oclazylo

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is : **

### YES

**

Instead of using local storage, I would suggest you with this to store the variables as a  **Factory**

You can have all the **application level variables** as

```
app.factory('appVariables', function() {
        var products=[];
        //some other variables you are using for the app
        return  {
                products:products
        }
    });
```

You need to modify your **ProductFactory** as

```
app.factory('ProductFactory',function($http,appVariables) {

   return  {
        getProduct:funtion(productCode)
        {
        if(appVariables.products!=null){
                //dbCall to retrieve products

        }
        else{
                //loop through the products array and return the product
        }
    }

   };
 });
```